# Bootstrap 4 issue with div content of different sizes

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am stuck with the following issue, as per the below script, where the data in a div is not always the same size, which results in the div NOT taking the entire horizontal space allocated by the use of the `col-6` class, from one row to the next:

```
 <div  class="card-body " >
  <div class="row comments_container" id="comments_container">
      <?php foreach ($comments AS $comment){?>
          <div class="callout <?php echo $comment['comment_callout'];?>">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-3"><?php echo '<span class="text-bold">De: </span>'.$comment['comment_author'];?></div>
                  <div class="offset-6 col-3">Envoyé le: <?php echo $comment['comment_date'];?></div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="offset-3 col-6 border-primary border-left">
                      <?php
                      if (!empty($comment['comment_parent_author'])){echo 'En réponse à '.$comment['comment_author'].'.<br/>';}
                      echo '<span class="text-xs">'.$comment['comment_content'].'</span>';
                      ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-3"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="row justify-content-center border-top mt-2 pt-2 border-thick border-primary w-100">
                  <div class="col-1">Approuver</div>
                  <div class="col-1">Répondre</div>
                  <div class="col-1">Indésirable</div>
                  <div class="col-1">Corbeille</div>
              </div>
          </div>
      <?php } ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see also from the below adjoined screenshot, when the `$comment['comment_content']` data is not the same size, or smaller, it results in the div containing the smallest data not 'respecting' the `col-6` class, eg. only taking the smallest data field's size

[image]

Comment: Try to use !important rule for that col-6 [more info](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

Answer (score 1):

Your classes are not formatted very well try this :

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container card-body">
  <div class="row comments_container" id="comments_container">
    <div class="col-3"><span class="text-bold">De:John john</span></div>
    <div class="offset-6 col-3">Envoyé le : 31 mai 2020 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="offset-3 col-6 border-primary border-left">
    <span class="text-xs">Commentaire</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center border-top mt-2 pt-2 border-thick border-primary w-100">
    <div class="p-1">Approuver</div>
    <div class="p-1">Répondre</div>
    <div class="p-1">Indésirable</div>
    <div class="p-1">Corbeille</div>
  </div>
</div>
```